# xamarin forms - using '(ProductModel)picker.BindingContext;' causing extra unnecessary post back

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, picker

Evening All,

Xamarin project using MVVM

Have a ProductModel with Id, Name and quantity.

ProductPage.xaml uses a listview to display a list of products. Picker, is binded to quantity, When a quantity is selected from the picker, OnPickerSelectedIndexChanged() is called and adds the product to an ObservableCollection DrinksToPurchaseList.  When the user clicks shopping cart, the DrinksToPurchaseList is added to a global OC which is then iterated through on the shopping cart VM and displayed on screen.

If the user wants to change the quantity on the ShoppingCart page they can use the picker to select a new value. QuantityChanged() is called on the shopping cart page and updates accordingly. This all works.

The problem I am facing is after this all happens OnPickerSelectedIndexChanged() on the productPage is then called again, which has nothing to do with what should be happening.

I have commented out the code until I found the issue.

```
var item = (ProductModel)picker.BindingContext;
```

in ProductPage

```
 void OnPickerSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var picker = (Picker)sender;
        var item = (ProductModel)picker.BindingContext;

        //Dummy Data used to test
        //var _productId = 1;
        //var _quantity = "4";
        //var _productName = "WINE 110011";
        //ProductModel item = new ProductModel(){ ProductId = _productId, ProductName = _productName, Quantity = _quantity};

         DrinksToPurchaseList.Add(item);
    }
```

I have removed this line and added in DD to test and everything works as it should.

I need  `var item = (ProductModel)picker.BindingContext;` to get the product and add it to the DrinksToPurchaseList.

Why is this happening and does anyone know a work around?

TY

```
     public class ProductModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            //Event
            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    
            //Fields
            private string _ProductName;
            private string _Quantity;
    
            //Constructor
            public ProductModel()
            {
                //Subscription
                this.PropertyChanged += OnPropertyChanged;
            }
    
            [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
            public int ProductId { get; set; }
    
            //Properties
            public string Quantity
            {
                get { return _Quantity; }
                set
                {
                    _Quantity = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
    
            public string ProductName
            {
                get { return _ProductName; }
                set
                {
                    _ProductName = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
    
            //OnPropertyChanged
            private void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.PropertyName == nameof(Quantity))
                {
                    //Do anything that needs doing when the Quantity changes here...
                    //var time = "hello
    
                    if (_Quantity == "0")
                    {
                       // Quantity = "6";
                    }
                }
            }
    
           // [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
            protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
            {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    
     public class ProductPageViewModel : BindableObject
        {
            public ObservableCollection<ProductModel> WineList { get; set; }
            public ObservableCollection<ProductModel> AllDrinksList { get; set; }
    
            public ProductPageViewModel()
            {
                WineList = new ObservableCollection<ProductModel>();
                WineList.Add(new ProductModel
                {
                    ProductId = 1,
                    ProductName = "Wine 101",
                    Quantity = "4",
                });
            
    
                AllDrinksList = new ObservableCollection<ProductModel>();
            }
        }
    public partial class ProductPage : ContentPage
    {
        public ProductPageViewModel productPage_ViewModal;
        private bool ZeroQuantitySelected = false;
        MainPage RootPage { get => Application.Current.MainPage as MainPage; }
        private ObservableCollection<ProductModel> DrinksToPurchaseList = new ObservableCollection<ProductModel>();
        private bool isWineListVisible = false;
    
        public ProductPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            productPage_ViewModal = new ProductPageViewModel();
            BindingContext = productPage_ViewModal;
        }
    
        private async void ShoppingCartClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            App.NewPageToLoad = "Shopping Cart";
            MenuPage tempMenu = new MenuPage();
            int IdOfMenuClicked = tempMenu.GetIdForNavigationMenu("Shopping Cart");
    
            App.globalShoppingCartOC = DrinksToPurchaseList;
            await RootPage.NavigateFromMenu(IdOfMenuClicked);
        }
    
        void OnPickerSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var picker = (Picker)sender;
//BELOW LINE IS THE ISSUE CAUSING THE OTHER POST BACK
            //var item = (ProductModel)picker.BindingContext;
            //DrinksToPurchaseList.Add(item);
             
            //Dummy Data used to test
            var _productId = 1;
            var _quantity = "4";
            var _productName = "WINE 110011";
            ProductModel item = new ProductModel() { ProductId = _productId, ProductName = _productName, Quantity = _quantity };
    
            DrinksToPurchaseList.Add(item);
    
        }
    }
    
    
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 x:Class="ScrollApp2.Views.ProductPage">
        <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
            <ToolbarItem Name="shoppingCartImg" Icon="xamarin_logo.png" Priority="0" Order="Primary" Activated="ShoppingCartClicked"/>
            <ToolbarItem x:Name="NoItemsInShoppingCart" Priority="0" Order="Primary" Activated="ShoppingCartClicked"/>
        </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    
        <ContentPage.Content>
            <StackLayout>
             
                <ListView  x:Name="producttablelist" IsVisible="True" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HasUnevenRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding WineList}" HeightRequest="1500">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <StackLayout HeightRequest="120" BackgroundColor="Green" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding ProductName}" TextColor="Black" VerticalOptions="Start"></Label>
    
                                        <Picker Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="2" VerticalOptions="Start" SelectedIndexChanged="OnPickerSelectedIndexChanged"  SelectedIndex="{Binding Quantity, Mode=TwoWay}">
                                            <Picker.Items>
                                                <x:String>0</x:String>
                                                <x:String>1</x:String>
                                                <x:String>2</x:String>
                                                <x:String>3</x:String>
                                                <x:String>4</x:String>
                                                <x:String>5</x:String>
                                                <x:String>6</x:String>
                                            </Picker.Items>
                                        </Picker>
                                    </Grid>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
    
                
            </StackLayout>
           
        </ContentPage.Content>
    </ContentPage>
    
    
     public class ShoppingCartViewModel
        {
            public ObservableCollection<ProductModel> ShoppingCartList { get; set; }
    
            public ShoppingCartViewModel()
            {
                ShoppingCartList = new ObservableCollection<ProductModel>();
            }
        }
    
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 x:Class="ScrollApp2.Views.ShoppingCartPage">
        <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
            <ToolbarItem Name="shoppingCartImg" Icon="shopping_cart.png" Priority="0" Order="Primary" Activated="ShoppingCartClicked"/>
            <ToolbarItem x:Name="NoItemsInShoppingCart" Priority="0" Order="Primary" Activated="ShoppingCartClicked"/>
        </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    
    
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="80*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="20*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    
            <StackLayout Grid.Row="0">
    
                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ShoppingCartList}" HasUnevenRows="True" SeparatorVisibility="None">
                    <ListView.Footer>
                        <Label x:Name="TotalForItems" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" VerticalTextAlignment="Start" Margin="20,20" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                    </ListView.Footer>
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
    
                                <Grid x:Name="ShoppingCartGrid" RowSpacing="25" ColumnSpacing="10">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    
                                    <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Id}" VerticalOptions="End" IsVisible="False"/>
                                    <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding ProductName}" VerticalOptions="End"/>
                                    <Picker Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="2" VerticalOptions="Start" SelectedIndexChanged="QuantityChanged" SelectedIndex="{Binding Quantity, Mode=TwoWay}">
                                        <Picker.Items>
                                            <x:String>0</x:String>
                                            <x:String>1</x:String>
                                            <x:String>2</x:String>
                                            <x:String>3</x:String>
                                            <x:String>4</x:String>
                                            <x:String>5</x:String>
                                            <x:String>6</x:String>
                                            <x:String>7</x:String>
                                        </Picker.Items>
                                    </Picker>
    
                                </Grid>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
    
    
            </StackLayout>
        </Grid>
        </ContentPage>
    
    public partial class ShoppingCartPage : ContentPage
        {
            ShoppingCartViewModel ShoppingCartViewModel = new ShoppingCartViewModel();
            private Dictionary<int, int> PickerUniquieIdDict = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    
            public decimal TotalForAllItems;
    
            public ShoppingCartPage ()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
    
                if (App.globalShoppingCartOC != null)
                {
                    // ProductModel P = new ProductModel();
                    //P.Add(new ProductModel { ProductId = 5, ProductName = "Gin", Image = "Gin.jpg", Description = "700ml", Price = 13.99M, Quantity = 0, SubTotalForItem = 0.00M, Genre = "Wine" });
    
                    //DUMMY DATA
                    //App.globalShoppingCartOC.Add(new ProductModel { ProductId = 5, ProductName = "Gin", Quantity="3" });
    
                    foreach (ProductModel Model in App.globalShoppingCartOC)
                    {
                        var _quantity = Convert.ToDecimal(Model.Quantity);
                        if (_quantity > 0)
                        {
                            ShoppingCartViewModel.ShoppingCartList.Add(Model);
                        }
                    }
                }
    
                if (App.GlobalWinePickerUniquieIdDict != null)
                {
                    PickerUniquieIdDict = App.GlobalWinePickerUniquieIdDict;
                }
    
                NoItemsInShoppingCart.Text = App.NoOfItemsInShoppingCartGlobalVar;
    
                this.BindingContext = this;
                BindingContext = ShoppingCartViewModel;
            }
    
            void QuantityChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                var x = 1;
            }
    
            void ShoppingCartClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                var x = 1;
            }
        }
```

Problem is that, product page loads, user selectes quantity and sets it to 3 for example.
User clicks shopping cart image, shopping cart page loads, user can select picker on shopping cart page to change quantity if they do this, the code posts back to

```
void QuantityChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var x = 1;
        }
```

on the shoping cart page, and then to the

```
 void OnPickerSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var picker = (Picker)sender;
        //var item = (ProductModel)picker.BindingContext;
        //Drink
```

on he product page.

Code shoudl not post back to OnPickerSelectedIndexChanged on the proudcpage from shopping cart page?

**UPDATE**
If you seen from my productModel.cs I am using INPC and it is working.

```
 public string Quantity
    {
        get { return _Quantity; }
        set
        {
            _Quantity = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

is being hit when the quantity on the picker is changed.

**My Question -> Hoever I need to perform additional logic on the VM after this happens which I dont know how to access....(which is the reason I was trying to use OnPickerSelectedIndexChanged()) would the best approach be to override the OnPropertyChanged() from productModel and call it from the ProductPageViewModel?**

Comment: `picker.BindingContext` is source data, but the `ProductModel` is class?Can you provide one simple that can reproduce your problem here? It is helpful for us to know your problem?

Comment: I have added more code to original Q, please have a lookTY

Comment: If you can upload your sample at github, I will download your sample to test, it will helpful to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Ahh Cherry that would be cool if you could take a quick look TY https://github.com/mlagan06/ScrollApp2

Comment: I download your sample and test, I find ProductModel's Quantity don't implement INotifyPropertyChanged correctly.

Comment: Hi Cherry....thanks for reply. So do you mean my logic is wrong? or that I shouldnt be using OnPickerSelectedIndexChanged()? as im already using INotiftPropertyChanged? for quantity? could you advise me how to resolve this please? TY...is it correct to have INotifyPropertyChanged  implemented from the ProductModel or should it be added to the view modals separately?

Comment: I suggest you don't use Picker, you can use  entry to binding quantity.

Comment: why does `ProductModel` subscribe to its own `PropertyChanged` event?

Comment: @Jason should this have been subscribed from the constructor in the ProductpageViewModel instead? and then use override for the OnPropertyChanged?

Comment: INPC is used by the data binding mechanism to monitor the model for changes and then update the UI.  **You** don't need to do anything under most circumstances.

Comment: OK so yes, this is all working, now as extra logic I have been trying to perform another task from the VM when quantity is changed. this is where the original problem lies. I am unsure how to do this could you offer any advice please. So when quantity is changed i want to call a function from the VM, thats why I was trying to use SelectedIndexChanged from the picker

Comment: call if from Quantity's setter

Comment: ive tired that. its flagging as 'the name 'SelectedIndexChanged ' does not exist in the current context. as it cant access a function in the VM from the setter of quantity in the produtModel