# INotifyPropertyChanged - Observable collection not posting back if UI field is changed

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged

I have been looking at many examples of INotifyPropertyChanged().

I went with the following example found on:

```
https://xamarindev.co.uk/mvvm-and-xamarin-forms/
```

Ive created a test project with this and it all works fine....using breakpoints I can see for example

```
public int Age
{
    get { return _person.Age; }
    set
    {
        _person.Age = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Age");
        OnPropertyChanged("UserInfo");
    }
}
```

is hit when the user changes the age on the app.

Only trouble with this one is that instead of one instance of the Person, I want multiple persons, so I have added in an ObservableCollection to look like:

```
    public class ViewModel1 : BaseModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<Person> _Persons;
    public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons
    {
        get { return _Persons; }
        set
        {
            if (_Persons == value) return;
            _Persons = value;
        }
    }

    private Person _person;
    public ViewModel1()
    {
        Persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

        //// set some default here for example
        _person = new Person
        {
            Age = 21,
            FirstName = "Steve",
            LastName = "Hawkins"
        };
        Persons.Add(_person);

        _person = new Person
        {
            Age = 19,
            FirstName = "JimBob",
            LastName = "Jones"
        };
        Persons.Add(_person);
    }

    public int Age
    {
        get { return _person.Age; }
        set
        {
            _person.Age = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Age");
            OnPropertyChanged("UserInfo");
        }
    }

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _person.FirstName; }
        set
        {
            _person.FirstName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
            OnPropertyChanged("UserInfo");
        }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return _person.LastName; }
        set
        {
            _person.LastName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("LastName");
            OnPropertyChanged("UserInfo");
        }
    }

    public string UserInfo
    {
        get
        {
            // return _person.PersonInfo();
            return _Persons[0].PersonInfo();
        }
    }
}
```

and then changed the View to display a ListView:

```
 <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
                      <ListView  x:Name="producttablelist" IsVisible="True" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HasUnevenRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" HeightRequest="1500">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout HeightRequest="120" BackgroundColor="Green" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Editor Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding FirstName, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" TextColor="Black" />
                                    <Editor Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding LastName, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" TextColor="Black" />
                                    <Editor Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Age, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" TextColor="Black" />
                                    <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding UserInfo}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" TextColor="Black" />
                                </Grid>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>

        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

So now, the page loads showing the 2 users, but if the user changes the age on the app...nothing happens..it doesnt post back to Age in the VM...

Could someone please help?

Been looking at other examples found on `https://riptutorial.com/xaml/example/28804/binding-to-a-collection-of-objects-with-inotifypropertychanged-and-inotifycollectionchanged`

and `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32667408/how-to-implement-inotifypropertychanged-in-xamarin-forms`

still cant seem to get it going if I use an ObservableCollection, and as I have other logic to add in when age is changed I would like this done from the VM not from the Person class (which some examples I have found have shown)

TY for any help

Comment: why do you have Age, etc properties on the VM instead of just using the properties that exist in the Person class?   Person should implement INPC for it's properties.  Your approach is really unusual.

Comment: Add your person model and the code where you change the age

Comment: @Jason thanks for the reply. I have properties on the VM because thats just the way the example I mentioned done it....I am working on from my Original Q https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64490129/xamarin-forms-using-productmodelpicker-bindingcontext-causing-extra-unnec in which Cherry mentioned my model properties doesnt implement INPC correctly So I have been working on that trying to figure out what I am doing wrong. If you have time could you take a quick look at that please

Comment: the "Age" entry is bound to the Age property of each person object in your data, not to the Age property of the base VM

Comment: ok cool thanks for the help Jason

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try using SetProperty, it inherits from INotifyPropertyChanged i.e write your public property like the code below:

```
    private ObservableCollection<Person> _persons;

    public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons
    {
        get => _persons;
        set => SetProperty(ref _persons, value);
    }
```

ps.... your baseModel might need to inherit from INotifyPropertyChanged too if you encounter issues. I also assumed you are using an MVVM framework like PrismMVVM

Answer (score 0):

As the Jason said: `the "Age" entry is bound to the Age property of each person object in your data, not to the Age property of the base VM` .

You do not need to write those properties in the ViewModel as they alreay exist in the Person Model.

What you really want to bind is  `Text="{Binding Person.FirstName, Mode=TwoWay}"` not `ViewModel1.FirstName`.

You can write `Text="{Binding FirstName, Mode=TwoWay}"` here as data-binding will search the root properties until it find the property `FirstName` in Model `Person`.

Refer: [data-bindings-to-mvvm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm)